# shell script returning null output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jq

I am not able to debug why it is returning

```
null
```

value. Can some-one please help into this.

Code -

```
getJSONParamater() {
       echo "Before : $1 $2 $3"
       eval "$3=$(cat $1 | jq '."$2"')"
       echo "After : $1 $2 $3"
}

return_value='default'
getJSONParamater etl-without-transformation.json  success_email return_value

echo $return_value
```

Comment: @Inian -  I just tried it and it works for me with double quotes

Comment: @devsda presumably its because `cat ... | jq ...` command is returning null

Comment: To debug a shell script, put `set -x` at the top. Then it will display each line as it executes it, so you can see what's going wrong.

Comment: At the very least, use `declare` instead of `eval` (although there are even better alternatives) to protect against (some) unintended code evaluation. An extreme example is `getJSONParameter f.json value ":; echo hi; name"`, which would echo "hi" before setting `name` equal to the result of the command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jq '."$2"'` will send literal `."$2"` as a expression for jq, what you want is:

```
jq --arg key "$2" '.[$key]' "$1"
```

Also removed useless use of `cat`.

I don't quite understand what you want with the eval part? But I guess you are trying to set `return_value` to the result from `jq`?

```
getJSONParameter() {
  jq --arg key "$2" '.[$key]' "$1"
}

return_value="$(getJSONParameter "etl-without-transformation.json" "success_email")"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it by using global variable:

```
return_value='default'
getJSONParamater() {
       return_value=$(cat "$1" | jq "$2")
}
getJSONParamater etl-without-transformation.json  .success_email
echo $return_value
```